# Proof the product of a convergent in measure sequence with a convergent sequence of real numbers converges in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  be a measure space and suppose $f_{n}:\left(X,\mathcal{F}\right)\to\mathbb{R}$
  converges in measure to $f$
  and $a_{n}$
  is a sequence of real numbers such that $a_{n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}a$
 . I want to show that $a_{n}f_{n}$
  converges in measure to $af$
 . Here is what I've done so far:

Given $\varepsilon>0$
  there are $D\in\mathcal{F}$
  and $N_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$
  such that $\mu\left(D\right)<\varepsilon$
  and for all $n\geq N_{1}$
  and $x\in D^{c}$
  we got $\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2\left(\sup\left|a_{n}\right|+1\right)}$
 . Also, since $a_{n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}a$
  there is an $N_{2}\in\mathbb{N}$
  such that $\left|a_{n}-a\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
  for all $n\geq N_{2}$
 . So for all $n\geq\max\left\{ N_{1},N_{2}\right\} $
  we get:$$\left|a_{n}f_{n}\left(x\right)-af\left(x\right)\right|\leq\left|a_{n}f_{n}\left(x\right)-a_{n}f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|a_{n}f\left(x\right)-af\left(x\right)\right|=\left|a_{n}\right|\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|a_{n}-a\right|\left|f\left(x\right)\right|<\frac{\left|a_{n}\right|\varepsilon}{2\left(\sup\left|a_{n}\right|+1\right)}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|$$
 My problem here is that I don't know that $f\left(x\right)$
  is bounded in $D^{c}$
  so I'm stuck with $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|$
  which I can't necessarily make arbitrarily small.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true without any extra conditions for example take $f_n=f=|x|$ on $\mathbb R$ then obviously $f_n\to f$ in measure but $\frac{1}{n}f$ doesnt converge in measure to $0$. The statement is true for finite measures(or if $f\in L^p$) and you can finish your proof in that case but using the fact $\mu(\{|f|\ge n\})\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ which is true in finite measures (or if $f\in L^p$).

Comment: I seem to have completely overlooked the added assumption that the space is finite... Well that definitely resolves it. Thanks!